# Does Future.traverse ensure the order of execution

Tags: scala, monads

Im using Future.traverse, is the order of execution guaranteed. My function `fn` must be called and the future completed before it runs for the next element.

```
val xs = Seq[T] ???
def fn(t: T): Future[Unit] = ??? 
Future.traverse(xs)(fn)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementation of `traverse` in scala 2.11:

```
  def traverse[A, B, M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]](in: M[A])(fn: A => Future[B])(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[A], B, M[B]], executor: ExecutionContext): Future[M[B]] =
    in.foldLeft(successful(cbf(in))) { (fr, a) =>
      val fb = fn(a)
      for (r <- fr; b <- fb) yield (r += b)
    }.map(_.result())
```

`val fb = fn(a)` creates `Future[B]` and only then composes with previously created future `for (r <- fr; b <- fb) yield (r += b)`. So answer is no. There is no execution order guarantee.

In scala 2.12 implementation changed:

```
def traverse[A, B, M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]](in: M[A])(fn: A => Future[B])(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[A], B, M[B]], executor: ExecutionContext): Future[M[B]] =
    in.foldLeft(successful(cbf(in))) {
      (fr, a) => fr.zipWith(fn(a))(_ += _)
    }.map(_.result())(InternalCallbackExecutor)
```

But again 'next' future is created before (first argument of zipWith is 'call by value') chaining with previous `fr`.

If you need to traverse sequentially then just make a little change of 2.11 implementation:

```
def traverse[A, B, M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]](in: M[A])(fn: A => Future[B])(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[A], B, M[B]], executor: ExecutionContext): Future[M[B]] =
    in.foldLeft(successful(cbf(in))) { (fr, a) =>
      for (r <- fr; b <- fn(a)) yield (r += b)
    }.map(_.result())
```

Comment: The reason I didn't reach for the source was the expectation that the implementation could change without the signature / docs changing.

But it's kind of moot if the source itself says that it's unordered, false positive vs false negative.

Comment: As for me documentation needs clarification about this behaviour. Example of usage does not directly follow from method description.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like it to me

[ScalaDocs 2.12.0](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#traverse[A,B,M[X]%3C:TraversableOnce[X]](in:M[A])(fn:A=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[B])(implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[M[A],B,M[B]],implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[M[B]])

> Asynchronously and non-blockingly transforms a TraversableOnce[A] into a Future[TraversableOnce[B]] using the provided function A => Future[B]. This is useful for performing a parallel map.

It's not specifically mentioned in the docs, so that means the contract could change if a more performant method existed. It also mentions "parallel map" so that's another hint that it's unlikely to preserve execution order.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have already stated: no, `traverse` doesn't (necessarily[1]) apply the transformation  sequentially, to completion, for the elements.

You could however, make something equivalent to [linearize](https://gist.github.com/viktorklang/3347939#file-linearize-scala)

Perhaps something like this:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.collection.mutable.Builder
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import language.higherKinds

/**
 * Linearize asynchronously applies a given function in-order to a sequence of values, producing a Future with the result of the function applications.
 * Execution of subsequent entries will be aborted if an exception is thrown in the application of the function.
 */
def linearize[T, U, C[T] <: Traversable[T]](s: C[T])(f: T => Future[U])(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[C[T], U, C[U]], e: ExecutionContext): Future[C[U]] = {
  def next(i: Iterator[T], b: Builder[U, C[U]]): Future[C[U]] =
    if(!i.hasNext) Future.successful(b.result)
    else Future.unit.flatMap(_ => f(i.next()).flatMap(v => next(i, b += v)))
  next(s.toIterator, cbf(s))
}
```

1: You could imagine a synchronous EC achieving a sequential effect tho.